# Must I exit my Git diff tool after each file in a merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-diff

I'm using a GUI difftool (p4merge, kdiff3, araxis, etc.) to view do my Git merges. This works great, but it seems that I need to quit the tool after editing each file in the merge in order for Git to move to the next file, and for it to complete the merge. Is there a way to avoid this?

Can I somehow iterate through all the files in the merge without quitting my merge tool between each? Even better, is there a way to have all of the files open together (so that, for example) I can coordinate my merge edits, possibly by moving back and forth among files), and then close the merge tool when I'm done with them all?

Comment: There should be some way to set up a diff tool that's a script that invokes another tool in the background, probably using something like `git difftool -y -x <your-script>`. My brief attempts to get this to work have not been successful.

Comment: That is difficult because git uses the exit state of the mergetool to find out whether you resolved the conflicts.

Comment: Use winmerge, esc exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to exit your git diff tool after each file in the merge. This is how git as a command line utility communicates with the diff tools. The more important question is: why is this a problem for you?

If you want to have another file open while doing your merge conflict resolution, you will have to run another instance of your mergetool. You can get access to the other versions of files via the `--ours` and `--theirs` switches to `git checkout`. But you would probably be better of with using something like `git checkout-index --stage=all`, which will store all versions in your temp directory.

You can make the merging a little bit less annoying by running `git mergetool -y` instead of `git mergetool`.

If you want to merge your files in a specific order, call `git status` to see a list of files that need resolving, then call `git mergetool -y <filename>` for each of those files.

And last but not least you can use the `git gui` – select a file that needs merging and start the mergetool from the contextmenu in the right hand panel. That way you can merge in any order and have multiple mergetools open at once.

Comment: It's just an issue (a) because of the time it takes (p4merge is slow to launch for me) and (b) I'd sometimes like to be able to work on the files in parallel, or in an arbitrary order, not the sequence that Git imposes.

Comment: Extended my answer and if p4merge is slow to launch you should probably upgrade you ram or run less programs :).

Comment: Git can detect file closes though. Is there no way to make closing of the file sufficient?

Comment: No – the git command line ui is a command line tool and is as such not made for multitasking.

Comment: How does "--wait" work when launching an editor? The effect is that Git waits for the file to close before continuing. So there seems to be a way to have it respond (in that case at least) to something other than application exit. That would deal with the exit-and-relaunch cycle I'm tring to avoid (but, as you point out, not the re-ordering or parallel opening).

Comment: There is no `--wait` switch anywhere in git.

Comment: In some editors (yes, not Git), for example BBEdit/TextWrangler, a `--wait` or similar flag will cause Git to wait until the editor closes the edited file before proceeding, rather than proceeding when the editor is exited. So Git appears to be able to distinguish exiting and file closing (at least) by programs it launches. In theory it could do that here to eliminate the close-reopen cycle; so I'm wondering if there's some way to in fact do that.

Comment: No – Git does not do anything special here. The text editor launches a ghost process that it will stop once you close the file. Git waits for this process – as usual. If you find a merge tool that will do that, you will indeed not have to close and reopen it, but will not have gained anything else. If your merge tool is too slow, don’t reinvent the wheel but fix your pc or use a faster merge tool ;).

Comment: Mergetool is p4merge and the "pc" has no performance issues with anything else.

Comment: If you have enough “free” RAM (>> 500MB), staring the same tool again and again should be fast. But if that doesn’t help, I would propose testing other mergetools.